# Distribution Profile not showing under Code Signing Identity BUT shows up in Accounts

Tags: ios, xcode5, code-signing

I have Xcode 5 and want to distribute my app, but my Distribution Profile is not showing under **Target** -> **Build Settings** -> **Code Signing Identity** ... There is just my Developer Profile but no Distribution Profile.

But the funny thing is that the Distribution Profile **is** linked to my Account (Xcode -> Preferences -> View Details -> Signing Identities). There is my Developer and Distribution Profile.

Do you know what could be wrong, or what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What you want to do? explain.. and check developer and distribution certificate in Provisional Profile of Xcode Organizer..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete the distribution certificate from keychain 
Revoke the Distribution Certificate, and create a new distribution certificate and profile.

Comment: thanks. now i'm able to choose my developer and distribution profile (for debug and release), but when i archive the app and want to validate it, it says that there are "no identities available for signing"...?

Comment: ah. i'm stupid. i forgot to make a new (not expired) distribution profile at itunes connect for my specific (in app purchase enabled) app, now it works!